# Karma-Jasmine How to test in angular a Router component

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, alert

I want to test this header component but I don't know how to do it, Im working with angular, just want to test a router function

This is the html

```
<header class="site-header">
  <nav class="navbar-home">
    <a (click)="routerTo('/home')">CIUDADELA </a> |
    <a (click)="routerTo('/request')">Solicitudes</a> |
    <a (click)="routerTo('/materials')">Materiales</a> |
  </nav>
</header>
```

And this is the header.component.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent{

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  routerTo(link : string): void {
    this.router.navigate([link]);
  }

}
```

And this is what coverage says that i need to test

[image]

Comment: You know there is a routerLink directive build in?

Comment: @enno.void But I can't test what I have? Sorry, I'm just learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a test like this to cover the call to router:

```
it('navbar-home item should call router.navigate',() => {
     const router= TestBed.inject(Router)
     spyOn(router, 'navigate')
     const firstLink = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.navbar-home')).children[0]
     firstLink .triggerEventHandler('click', '/home');
     fixture.detectChanges()
     expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/home']);
  });
```

same way you cann check call to you're components function.

you need to provide the router in your test setup